# C# Reading file as bytes, converting it to UTF-8, then back ruins the data

Tags: c#, utf-8

When I read the file as Bytes, convert it to UTF8 (so I can edit contents later) but then convert it back to Bytes and save it, it messes up the file and adds random stuff to it. The size goes from 11,096 KB to 17,692 KB.

```
private void inj()
        {
            string appAsarPath = this.filePath + "app.asar";
            this.backupAsar = File.ReadAllBytes(appAsarPath);
            string asarContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(this.backupAsar);
            File.WriteAllBytes(appAsarPath, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(asarContents));
        }
```

Here are some of the contents of the file.
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to read it straight to text? Why the bytes first? Although I know that doesn't explain why it's getting messed up. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I originally read it as text but the same thing happend and I was trying different things. @GeorgeKerwood

Comment: Do you know for certain that original file is UTF8? Was it written by your own code?

Comment: I don't know the encoding of the file. I'm 99% sure the file was created using https://github.com/electron/asar. @GeorgeKerwood

Comment: Did you try ASCII?  Otherwise if you can host the file somewhere and share a link, I'll take a look. Nothing is obviously wrong with you code so I'd need to test.

Comment: Using ASCII makes lots of things just turn into "?" rather than the ? in a diamond. Here is the [file](https://file.io/mcEM8cIX) so you can take a look

Comment: Okay. I'm getting 404, file not found on that link.

Comment: It might have been automatically deleted when I clicked it to test if it worked. [try this](https://file.io/gE7lQ7Lj) and if it doesn't work, do you have a discord I could add you on quickly and send there?

Comment: [asar describes its file format in the readme](https://github.com/electron/asar/blob/master/README.md#format) which does not sound like it would cleanly decode in any text encoding. You would need to prune off the non-text bytes first.

Comment: Okay, I've got it, although perhaps I shouldn't have as it's marked copyright. This isn't a continuous text file, it's some propriety structure.  The very first line is JSON, which is the meta of the file describing the structure. It tells you which objects can be found from which byte address and their sizes. There's even binary encoded images in here so you will not be able to simply read it to string. You will need to deserialize and understand the first line, to then read out the parts you are interested in.

Comment: Could you provide a solution where I would be able to read the file but then edit the contents and then save it with the non-text bytes? If any of the bytes of out of order or in the wrong place it wont work because asar uses offsets + size.